# Keras - CNN Model Summary Diemension Interpretation

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, convolution

I am using Keras library to build this deep learning model: INPUT(depth=1, height=15, width=27) -> CONV[depth=8](height=4, width=27) -> POOL(height=2, width=1) -> (Regression) output.

I expect the ouput shape from convolution2d_1 to be (None, 8, 12, 1) and thence, the ouput shape from pooling2d_1 to be (None, 8, 6, 1); while I am getting (None, 8, 15, 27) and (None, 8, 7, 27) respectively.

What am I doing or interpreting wrong here?

P.S.: Also, this setting gives a Baseline Error: 99.23%!

```
print "SHAPE OF INPUT IS:", num_train_3D, depth, height, width
inp = Input(shape=(depth, height, width)) 
conv_1 = Convolution2D(8, 4, 27, border_mode='same', activation='relu')(inp)
pool_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 1))(conv_1)
''' Now flatten to 1D, apply FC -> ReLU (with dropout) -> softmax '''
flat = Flatten()(pool_1)
out = Dense(1)(flat)  #regression

model = Model(input=inp, output=out) # To define a model, just specify its input and output layers

print "Model Summary:"
print model.summary()
```

=====================================

```
SHAPE OF INPUT IS: 53745 1 15 27
Model Summary:
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to                     
====================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)             (None, 1, 15, 27)     0                                            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
convolution2d_1 (Convolution2D)  (None, 8, 15, 27)     872         input_1[0][0]                    
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
maxpooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 8, 7, 27)      0           convolution2d_1[0][0]            
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)              (None, 1512)          0           maxpooling2d_1[0][0]             
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 1)             1513        flatten_1[0][0]                  
====================================================================================================
Total params: 2,385
Trainable params: 2,385
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `border_mode='same'` to `border_mode='valid'`. Border mode `same` adds zero padding to the input to make sure that the output of the convolutional layer has the same shape as its input. With border mode `valid` convolution is performed only where the input and the filter fully overlap.

Comment: Thanks, it does solve the dimension mismatch; but can you comment on that baseline error of 99.23%, I am still getting the exact same!

Comment: It is difficult to say anything about the error without any details. Are you talking about the training error or the test one? What about your data set? Provide a minimal reproducible example and all necessary details to get constructive feedback on the error issue. I would suggest to do that in a new question, this one is about dimensions.

Comment: Sure, I would try on my own for some time and then would do it, if needed :)