# Keras output shape and model summary (Xception)

Tags: deep-learning, keras

My question is a different from these questions as it's related to a built-in model.

[Keras cnn model output shape doesn't match model summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475827/keras-cnn-model-output-shape-doesnt-match-model-summary)

[Keras - CNN Model Summary Diemension Interpretation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869984/keras-cnn-model-summary-diemension-interpretation)

I'm trying to examine the built-in Xception model for transfer learning and used 
model.summary():

Here are the first few layers of the Xception model

```
 Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param      Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, None, None, 3 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 3 864         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1_bn (BatchNormaliza (None, None, None, 3 128         block1_conv1[0][0]               
______________________________________________________________________________________
```

My concern is with the depth channel.
Shouldn't the depth output of the block1_conv1 (Conv2D)  be 32 and not 3?

If I figure out the output via get_layer, I get the correct output:

```
base_model.get_layer(index = 1).output
<tf.Tensor 'block1_conv1/convolution:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, 32) dtype=float32>



base_model = Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
print(base_model.summary())
```

Comment: This is not a valid question. If you carefully observe that line you can see the right parentheses is missing. It should be `(None, None, None, 32)` but the `summary()` function prints with fixed number of columns therefore `2)` was missing. Btw, on my computer I saw `(None, None, None, 32`.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm running it from the Python shell that comes with Python. What are you running it from?

Comment: I run it in my Linux terminal.